# How to create a prompt with options after yarn start

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, package.json, yarn-workspaces

I'm working within a repo that has two React apps installed in a subfolder. A developer chooses which project to run by entering `yarn app-1` or `yarn app-2`.

`yarn start` is currently unused. If a developer runs `yarn start`, instead of **"Command 'start' not found"** I would like to ask them which application they'd like to run, show the two options, and then run the correct command for their selection.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a tool like [`Inquirer.js`](https://youtu.be/_oHByo8tiEY).

For the setup, check the npm package or the video [`I created a Command Line Game for you // 5-Minute Node.js CLI Project` from Fireship's Youtube channel](https://youtu.be/_oHByo8tiEY).